# Combining multiple Var outputs into one div

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code

```js
   var words = [
   'TEST',
   'Test2',
]

function randomize() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length));
    document.getElementById('Word1').innerHTML = words[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length));
    document.getElementById('Word2').innerHTML = words[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    document.getElementById('Number1').innerHTML = randomNumber;
    
    document.getElementById('Combine').innerHTML = 'Word1' + 'Word2' + 'Number1';


}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Word1">
    <!-- Word1 will display here -->
  </div>

  <div id="Word2">
      <!-- Word2 will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Number1">
      <!-- Number will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Combine">
    <!-- Word1Word2Number1  Will display here-->
  </div>

  <button onclick="randomize()" )>Generate</button>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

as you can see I need the last one to output to DIV "Combine" in the html but combining the first 3 together into an unbroken string.

What am I doing wrong here, been banging my head on this for sometime now. Been several years since I did any javascript at all.

Comment: Store the results into a variable and use the variable

Comment: FYI it is possible for your random words to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different variables for each random choice, then concatenate them in the last DIV.

```js
var words = [
  'TEST',
  'Test2',
]

function randomize() {
  var randomWord1 = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length))];
  document.getElementById('Word1').innerHTML = randomWord1;

  var randomWord2 = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length))];
  document.getElementById('Word2').innerHTML = randomWord2;

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
  document.getElementById('Number1').innerHTML = randomNumber;

  document.getElementById('Combine').innerHTML = randomWord1 + randomWord2 + randomNumber;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Word1">
    <!-- Word1 will display here -->
  </div>

  <div id="Word2">
    <!-- Word2 will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Number1">
    <!-- Number will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Combine">
    <!-- Word1Word2Number1  Will display here-->
  </div>

  <button onclick="randomize()" )>Generate</button>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just grab the element HTML at the moment, map it to an array and then join with a space. To facilitate this, I gave each element a similar class that could be queried.

Explanation:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.word')] // this takes all the matching elements and puts them into an array that can be iterated
   .map(e => e.innerHTML) // this maps that element array into an array of just each ones innerHTML
   .join(' '); // this joins the array with a space
```

```js
var words = [
   'TEST',
   'Test2',
]

function randomize() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length));
    document.getElementById('Word1').innerHTML = words[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length));
    document.getElementById('Word2').innerHTML = words[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    document.getElementById('Number1').innerHTML = randomNumber;
    
    document.getElementById('Combine').innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('.word')].map(e => e.innerHTML).join(' ');


}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='word' id="Word1">
    <!-- Word1 will display here -->
  </div>

  <div class='word' id="Word2">
      <!-- Word2 will display here -->
  </div>
  <div class='word' id="Number1">
      <!-- Number will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Combine">
    <!-- Word1Word2Number1  Will display here-->
  </div>

  <button onclick="randomize()" )>Generate</button>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest to not use the same variable for multiple operations. You are not going to achieve great optimizations with this. It just confuses you and reduces readability.

Also, you are adding strings ( 'Word1' + 'Word2' + 'Number1') directly in your `combine div` innerHTML. You need to combine the `string variables`.

```js
var words = [
   'TEST',
   'Test2',
]

function randomize() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length));
    document.getElementById('Word1').innerHTML = words[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (words.length));
    document.getElementById('Word2').innerHTML = words[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    document.getElementById('Number1').innerHTML = randomNumber;
    
    document.getElementById('Combine').innerHTML = randomNumber + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;


}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Word1">
    <!-- Word1 will display here -->
  </div>

  <div id="Word2">
      <!-- Word2 will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Number1">
      <!-- Number will display here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Combine">
    <!-- Word1Word2Number1  Will display here-->
  </div>

  <button onclick="randomize()" )>Generate</button>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```